# Turn Texture Blending off in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I am currently drawing single colored pixels to my texture in XNA.  However, there seems to be blending occuring, as the color I draw on the screen gets blended with my background color.  How can I turn this off so that the color I draw is only the color I draw?

```
this.spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1), [My Color]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the methods above without any luck.  Instead I created a 1x1 solid white pixel and used that as a base to color on.  It solved the blending problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check the alpha channel of "[My Color]".

Alternatively:

```
device.RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a [SpriteBlendMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spriteblendmode.aspx) enumeration into your [SpriteBatch.Begin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195101.aspx) call to turn off alpha blending:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteBlendMode.None);
```

Comment: SpriteBlendMode is not in XNA 4.0+